# How to find the CDF of $\min(X,a)$ if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X$ is uniform on $[0, 2]$. Find the CDF of $Y = min(X,a)$.

I'm not sure how to attack this problem. The CDF is the probability that $Y$ is less or equal to $y$. But how would you derive that from $X$? I don't see how they connect.

Comment: I know I have to break it up into cases. Such if a<0 then y=a, if a>2 then y=x.

Comment: Please watch out for your title and tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to attack this problem. The CDF is the probability that 
>   $Y$ is less or equal to $y$ .

$\def\P{\mathop{\sf P}} \P(Y\leq y)$

> But how would you derive that from $X$? I don't see how they connect.

$Y=\min(X,a)$ so, we should consider the cases $a\leq y$ and $y< a$. $$\begin{align}\P(Y\leq y) ~&=~ \P(\min (X,a)\leq y)\\[1ex]&=~\mathbf 1_{a\leq y}+\mathsf P(X\leq y)\cdot\mathbf 1_{y<a}\\[1ex]&=~\begin{cases}1 &:& a\leq y\\\mathsf P(X\leq y)&:& y< a \end{cases}\end{align}$$

Because, if $a$ is at most $y$, then *certainly* $\min(X,a)$ is too.   Whereas if $a$ is greater than $y$, then $\min(X,a)$ is at most $y$ only when $X$ is.

Comment: Graham why is a>Y = 1. And also whats if a was negative or what if a was greater than two? Wouldn't that affect the cdf?

Comment: @Allan See edit. watch out for Did

Comment: @Allan, if $a$ is negative (or simply at most $y$) then *certainly* $\min(X,a)$ is too.  If $a$ is greater than $y$ then $\min(X,a)$ is at most $y$ only when $X$ is.  ( In hind sight, probably easier to have partitioned straight away using that. )